# Error with online membership payment "Payment Method is a required field."

Tags: civimember

WP 6.2.2 civi 5.61.1
For online membership signup or renewal(withchecksum) the form will not submit. With or without priceset
Error is "Payment Method is a required field."
Works OK when logged in so assuming permissions - although I thought checksum would override that - the form does prefill OK.
Checksum link does not fill membership ID eg civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=1&cs=36d4d672600cb6aa71cd87f44b48a073_1685662618_168&cid=2157&mid=
Filling it manually makes no difference.
Anonymous user has all profile & membership permissions plus on-line contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make sure all the membership types included on the page have either auto-renewal have same options i.e required or optional or no-renewal.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep that got me a bit further but now I have Stripe not working for anonymous users - will start new thread cheers